# VPN keeps getting disconnected in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, vpn

I got two PCs. One is a Microsoft surface with Windows 10. The other one is a gaming notebook with Ubuntu. I use a VPN to connect to my office.

When I do this, once I connect to it, the Ubuntu one has no problem.
However with the windows 10, if I leave it unattended, the VPN gets disconnected after a while.

Why can this be happening and how do I make sure the windows machine stays connected like the ubuntu one?

Comment: Look for timeout variables in the VPN client. That is a common issue.

Comment: where in windows 10 I can set this?

Comment: Which VPN client are you using? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: You need to check your VPN documation'

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check your VPN config file or documentation, maybe your config file has a default "10 min timeout" value that you need to change or maybe add a line to avoid that disconnection from happening.

Comment: Where can I find those config files? I checked Windows VPN setup and I couldn't find anything

Comment: Check this Microsoft Article, it specifies the creation of an XML profile in which you set an "Always On" parameter within it. It would be best if you also considered using another VPN client (external software), Win10's VPN doesn't always work well, I had changed it 2 times when it was not behaving nicely.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-access/vpn/always-on-vpn/deploy/vpn-deploy-client-vpn-connections

Hope it helps!